# integration over functions of scalar products

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

let $k\cdot x$ and $n \cdot x$ be scalar products of 3 component vectors, $k_i\in(k_1,k_2,k_3),\,\, n_i, \,\,x_i$. Define two functions, $f,g$ 
 which are related via a partial derivative ,

$$ g(k\cdot x)=\int^{k\cdot x}\!f(\xi)\, \text{d}\xi, \quad \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} =k_i\,f(k\cdot x)$$

My question is, can I define another function, $h(k\cdot x)$ which returns a component of the new vector $n_i$ as a co product of $f(k\cdot x)$ when differentiated. That is, I want to find $h$ such that

$$ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} =n_i\,f(k\cdot x)$$

I want to do something like including a rotation matrix $R$ which rotates the vector $n$ onto $k$ and write,

$$ h(k\cdot x)=\int^{n\cdot x}\!f(R\xi)\, \text{d}\xi$$

However, I'm not sure if this is a valid operation. Can anyone elucidate, or come up with a different way of doing it?

Comment: Over what space are you doing the integration in the definition of $g$.

Comment: In the definition it is $R^1$, but it can be anything for $h$ as long as I get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Take $n_1= 1,n_2 = 0, n_3 = 1$, then
$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_1} = 0
$$

$$
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2} = 0
$$

from the first you conclude that $h$ does not depend on $x_1$ and the second that $h$ does not depend on $x_2$ so we conclude that
$$
\frac{\partial h(x_3)}{\partial x_3} = f(k\cdot x) 
$$
L.h.s. does only depend on $x_3$ and r.h.s. depends generally on all $x_1,x_2,x_3$. A contradiction.

The question is for which $n$, there is a solution. Assume that there is two independent vectors $n,m$. That has a solutions $h_n,h_m$, then it is possible to combine $n$ and $m$ so that one coordinate is zero and another is nonzero. Again similarly if $k_i$ is nonzero for all $i$ we will get a contradiction, then the possible $n$ is equal to some $c k$. If say $k_1=0$ if then $n_1$ is nonzero then the $h$ from the first equation would give
$$
h = x_1 n_1 f(k\cdot x) + c(x_2,x_3)
$$
and then the derivation of $h$ in a coordinate with nonzero $k_j$ would lead to l.h.s. depending on $x_1$ but not r.h.s. again a contradiction. Hence all possible $n$ is in the linear space generated by $k$.

Comment: What about this attempt using matrices and 2D for convenience, $$ h=[1\,\,1]\int^{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}n_1 x_1+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}n_2 x_2} f\left(\left([1\,\, 0]\frac{k_1}{n_1}+[0\,\, 1]\frac{k_2}{n_2}\right)\xi\right) \text{d}\xi $$ Do you think this is valid?